# How to improve a DensityPlot?

Tags: plotting

Given that

```
x1 = 
  -((π^2 (x - x0) Cosh[π (x - x0)]) /
   (2 (-Cos[π (y - y0)] + Cosh[π (x - x0)]))) + (π^2 (x - x0) Cosh[π (x - x0)]) / 
   ( 2 (-Cos[π (-1 + y + y0)] + Cosh[π (x - x0)])) + (π^2 (x - x0) Sinh[π (x - x0)]^2) / 
   ( 2 (-Cos[π (y - y0)] + Cosh[π (x - x0)])^2) - (π^2 (x - x0) Sinh[π (x - x0)]^2) / 
   ( 2 (-Cos[π (-1 + y + y0)] + Cosh[π (x - x0)])^2)
```

I want to do a density plot by using:

```
DensityPlot[ x1 /. {x0 -> 0, y0 -> 0.2}, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But there are some white regions which are not plotted by density color. How to plot the density color also in the white regions?

Comment: Try `PlotRange->All`

Comment: Use `PlotPoints -> 80`

Answer (score 1):

`ContourPlot` gives a clearer picture here:

```
ContourPlot[x1 /. {x0 -> 0, y0 -> 0.2}, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, -0.5, 0.5},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 15,
 ContourLines -> False,
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]
```

[image]

Compare:

```
DensityPlot[x1 /. {x0 -> 0, y0 -> 0.2}, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, -0.5, 0.5},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

Or concentrate on the "critical area":

```
DensityPlot[x1 /. {x0 -> 0, y0 -> 0.2}, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, -0.5, 0.5},
 PlotRange -> {{-0.3, 0.3}, {-0.1, 0.5}},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 ClippingStyle -> {Blue, Red},
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]
```

[image]